# classic .net app pool + iis 7.5 + compression modules

Tags: iis

I have windows 2008 r2 installed on my server, so iis 7.5 is.
I am not able run any of the class.net applications on iis. one of the compression modules throws exception.

Detailed Error Information
Module DynamicCompressionModule 
Notification SendResponse 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x8007007e 
Requested URL http://localhost:8081/a.html 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\TestWebSite\a.html 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous

i tried diferent logon methods, different sites even static html pages are not served. Error never changes.

sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick bit of searching found this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1149768.aspx.  Are you running a 64bit server?  If so, is it possible you are (potentially inadvertently) mixing 32bit and 64bit code in the same application pool?

More information with slightly more detailed steps to resolve the problem found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx (search down for error code 0x8007007e)

> Error Message:
>
> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error  The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is
>   invalid. Module
>   DynamicCompressionModule  Notification
>   SendResponse  Handler StaticFile 
>   Error Code 0x8007007e  Requested URL
>   http://localhost:80/  Physical Path
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot  Logon Method
>   Anonymous  Logon User Anonymous
>
> Reason:
>
> Error Code 0x8007007e is:
>
> ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND - The specified
>   module could not be found.
>
> This problem occurs because the
>   ApplicationHost.config file or the
>   Web.config file references a module
>   that is invalid or that does not
>   exist. To resolve this problem: In the
>   ApplicationHost.config file or in the
>   Web.config file, locate the module
>   reference or the DLL reference that is
>   invalid, and then fix the reference.
>   To determine which module reference is
>   incorrect, enable Failed Request
>   Tracing, and then reproduce the
>   problem.
>
> For above specific error (mentioned in
>   this example),
>   DynamicCompressionModule module is
>   causing the trouble. This is because
>   of the XPress compression scheme
>   module (suscomp.dll) which gets
>   installed with WSUS. Since Compression
>   schemes are defined globally and try
>   to load in every application Pool, it
>   will result in this error when 64bit
>   version of suscomp.dll attempts to
>   load in an application pool which is
>   running in 32bit mode.
>
> This module entry looks like:
>
> Hence to get rid of this problem:
>
> Ø Remove/Disable the XPress
>   compression scheme from the
>   configuration using the command below:
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
>   set config
>   -section:system.webServer/httpCompression
>   /-[name='xpress']
>
> OR
>
> Ø Add an attribute of "precondition=
>   "64bitness" for this module entry so
>   that it loads only in 64bit
>   application pools
>
> Refer this blog for more details on
>   Preconditions in IIS7
>
> OR
>
> Ø Use a 32bit version of suscomp.dll

Comment: many many thank daniel. 

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']

this command fixed my problem.

Comment: changing the compression is working for this case.